# return Post::all(); - Laravel version 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I've recently started looking into laravel.

im trying to return some data from a table however i'm getting the following error:

Error
Class 'App\Post' not found

on this line:
return Post::all();

here is the code in my PostsContoller file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Post;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return Post::all();
        return view('posts.index');
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in what namespace did you define your `Post` model and in what folder did you put it?

Comment: I added Route::resource('posts', 'App\Http\Controllers\PostsController'); to the routes/web.php

creates a Post.php in the models folder with the following code

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Post` model is not `App\Post` it is `App\Models\Post` as it is defined in the `App\Models` namespace.

```
use App\Models\Post;
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the Laravel version 8, they have moved the Models (as a folder) in the App\Models, so your model Post will be in the App\Models\Post directory,
in previous version of laravel it was App\Post directly.

Here is [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#defining-models) regarding models in Laravel 8

So, always remember to import the model by

```
use App\Models\model_name;
```

Hope it helps, Thank You :)